# Wi-fi won't work on my Lenovo. please help

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

I'm using a **Lenovo G50-80** and i installed **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** last week, but for some reason i can't connect it to wifi without ethernet.

I've tried a handful of different options on this forum, but the option to enable wifi on the top bar still won't appear

Here's my Wireless-info:
http://www.mediafire.com/download/3z77zh746ezdvvy/wireless-info.txt

thank you

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2xIFqWY.png this is what my connection panel looks like. the option to enable wi-fi is not there. i checked to make sure it's not hard-locked.

Comment: This suggests that the correct driver isn't being loaded. Please open a terminal and do: `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` Please paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: i got an error message saying "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available"

Answer (score 0):

With the ethernet temporarily connected, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After it completes, detach the ethernet and reboot. If the wireless is not working, please show us:

```
sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl
```

Comment: sorry for the long wait. i did it and it still doesn't work. when i try the modprobe command it still gives me  "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available"

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/770490/broadcom-wireless-drivers-unclaimed-after-installing-update-16-04/770774#770774