# Realtek Wireless Drivers unclaimed after installing 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, realtek-wireless

My context: Long-term 16.04 user but still a noob (just appreciate the relatively minimal OS). New laptop, installed 18.04, completely replacing Windows 10. Been unfruitfully trying to solve this for hours.

My problem appears to be similar to that of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770490/broadcom-wireless-drivers-unclaimed-after-installing-update-16-04), however their solution does not work for me.

To mimic the information they provide:

1. `sudo lshw -C network` returns:

`*-network UNCLAIMED

       description: Network controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a4300000-a430ffff`

(along with ethernet information)

2. `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` returns:

`07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b023]
    Kernel modules: r8822be, wl, rtl8822be`

3. `sudo modprobe wl && dmesg | grep wl` returns:

`[    0.000000] ACPI Error: [TPLD] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/dswload-378)
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: [TPD0] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20170831/dswload-210)
[    0.000000] ACPI Error: [_ON_] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/dswload-378)
[   19.701890] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   19.701891] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:7299:2c6dbf84
[   21.147567] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 550 at /home/jeremy/backport-iwlwifi/net/wireless/reg.c:2294 wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory+0xb6/0xe0 [cfg80211]
[   21.147770] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 550 at /home/jeremy/backport-iwlwifi/net/wireless/reg.c:2308 wiphy_apply_custom_regulatory+0xc3/0xe0 [cfg80211]
[   21.148377] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 550 at /home/jeremy/backport-iwlwifi/net/wireless/core.c:855 wiphy_register+0x8bf/0x8f0 [cfg80211]
[   21.682507] Modules linked in: wl(POE+) joydev snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm btusb snd_seq_midi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal r8822be(CE) mac80211(OE) intel_powerclamp snd_seq_midi_event btrtl coretemp hid_multitouch snd_rawmidi btbcm btintel bluetooth 8250_dw cfg80211(OE) snd_seq wmi_bmof kvm ecdh_generic irqbypass compat(OE) intel_cstate intel_wmi_thunderbolt intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer idma64 virt_dma snd mei_me shpchp nvidia_uvm(POE) intel_lpss_pci mei input_leds ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi serio_raw mac_hid intel_lpss soundcore typec processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel wmi sch_fq_codel ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_core iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi parport_pc
[   21.682575]  wl_module_init+0x89/0x8b [wl]
[   21.914773] WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 550 at /home/jeremy/backport-iwlwifi/net/mac80211/rate.c:125 ieee80211_rate_control_register+0x5e/0xf0 [mac80211]
[   21.914773] Modules linked in: rtlwifi(OE+) snd_hda_codec wl(POE) joydev snd_hda_core snd_hwdep snd_pcm btusb snd_seq_midi intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal r8822be(CE) mac80211(OE) intel_powerclamp snd_seq_midi_event btrtl coretemp hid_multitouch snd_rawmidi btbcm btintel bluetooth 8250_dw cfg80211(OE) snd_seq wmi_bmof kvm ecdh_generic irqbypass compat(OE) intel_cstate intel_wmi_thunderbolt intel_rapl_perf snd_seq_device snd_timer idma64 virt_dma snd mei_me shpchp nvidia_uvm(POE) intel_lpss_pci mei input_leds ucsi_acpi typec_ucsi serio_raw mac_hid intel_lpss soundcore typec processor_thermal_device int3403_thermal int3400_thermal intel_soc_dts_iosf intel_pch_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_pad acpi_thermal_rel wmi sch_fq_codel ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_core iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi`

**Additional stuff**

Ubuntu tells me "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found". There are no updates for this driver in "Software and Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" (even after checking all the additional "Downloadable from the internet" options under "Ubuntu Software").

I have tried countless solutions (that I have since loss track of) related to using GitHub repos for downloading the drivers.

Secure Boot is disabled.

**Maybe important**: I read somewhere that I may need to physically turn on the Wi-Fi adapter, and I am worried this may the problem because I turned off the Wi-Fi when installing Ubuntu 18.04 (was using ethernet for faster download) and have no apparent keyboard shortcut to turn it back on if that is the problem.