# How to fix the problem "Wifi adapter not found" in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wireless, hp

I have installed Ubuntu in my HP laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) recently. But after the installation, wireless Wi-Fi was not working. So that time, I had solved this problem from this site using some command. But after few days, again the same problem arises. Now again I followed the same procedure, but it is not working. I have used the following commands and error also given below.

**$ sudo apt-get install build-essential**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.4ubuntu1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 libfwup1 libllvm8 libopenal-data libopenal1
  libwayland-egl1-mesa linux-headers-4.15.0-76 linux-headers-4.15.0-76-generic
  linux-headers-5.3.0-26 linux-headers-5.3.0-26-generic
  linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-26-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-26-generic ubuntu-web-launchers
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 libfwup1 libllvm8 libopenal-data libopenal1
  libwayland-egl1-mesa linux-headers-4.15.0-76 linux-headers-4.15.0-76-generic
  linux-headers-5.3.0-26 linux-headers-5.3.0-26-generic
  linux-image-5.3.0-26-generic linux-modules-5.3.0-26-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-26-generic ubuntu-web-launchers
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**$ git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git**

```
fatal: destination path 'rtlwifi_new' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

**$ cd rtlwifi_new/**

**~/rtlwifi_new$ git checkout origin/extended -b extended**

```
fatal: A branch named 'extended' already exists.
```

**~/rtlwifi_new$ git branch**

```
* extended
```

**~/rtlwifi_new$ sudo make install**

```
make -C /lib/modules/5.3.0-28-generic/build M=/home/amit/rtlwifi_new modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/amit/rtlwifi_new/btcoexist/halbtc8192e2ant.o
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fstack-protector-strong’
scripts/Makefile.build:288: recipe for target '/home/amit/rtlwifi_new/btcoexist/halbtc8192e2ant.o' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/amit/rtlwifi_new/btcoexist/halbtc8192e2ant.o] Error 1
scripts/Makefile.build:519: recipe for target '/home/amit/rtlwifi_new/btcoexist' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/amit/rtlwifi_new/btcoexist] Error 2
Makefile:1655: recipe for target '_module_/home/amit/rtlwifi_new' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/amit/rtlwifi_new] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-28-generic'
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**~/rtlwifi_new$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de**

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found.
```

**~/rtlwifi_new$ sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de**

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8723de not found.
```

Thanks in advance.

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Comment: Does [this](https://ibcomputing.com/install-rtl8723de-realtek-d723-ubuntu-18-04/) help?

Comment: Try:
`lshw -C network` For me it was showing unclaimed for the wifi adapter. Then I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770490/broadcom-wireless-drivers-unclaimed-after-installing-update-16-04). and [also here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69199/wireless-not-working-after-update-network-unclaimed). The problem is said to be with the incomplete installation or missing driver