# My computer does not connect to WiFi anymore

Tags: networking

So I have an HP laptop and Ubuntu does not have the drivers for my wifi, so I had to use other drivers I do not know exactly which were all I remember is that it is rtl8723de. So all went smooth since then, except now, Ubuntu says that there is not wifi adapter. I need a little bit of help

The output of the command lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list is:

02.00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor 
              Co., Ltd Device [10ec:d723]
0: hci0:Bluetooth
               soft blocked: no
               hard blocked: no

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1212551/how-to-fix-the-problem-wifi-adapter-not-found-in-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: This should work https://askubuntu.com/a/988947/167850

Comment: tried but at `sudo dkms build rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414` out puts `Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=5.3.0-40-generic.....(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8723de: 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414/build/make.log for more information.
`

Comment: Well. That one doesn't build either. So clone `lwfinger` `master`.

Comment: welp... I am a linux noob, do I use git clone lwfinger master?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1018851/167850 But omit `-b extended`.

Comment: when the last command is run `sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6` it outputs `Module rtlwifi-new/0.6 already installed on kernel 5.3.0-40-generic/x86_64
`

Comment: Run `sudo dkms remove rtlwifi-new/0.6 --all` and start again.