# Ubuntu server 20.04 no wifi

Tags: drivers, wireless, broadcom

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04, but the wifi interface is hard blocked.
I tried to install `firmware-b43-installer` and to insert the brcm80211 module manually but no luck.
Is there a known solution for this?

```
$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: wlp4s0b1
   version: 01
   serial: 70:f1:a1:ca:27:b5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=5.4.0-31-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:17 memory:f0300000-f0303fff

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300 [1028:0010]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v1.1 Fast Ethernet [1969:2060] (rev c1)
```

Comment: For Broadcom Wi-Fi I think you should install broadcom-sta-dkms and broadcom-sta-common packages  . Those worked in my case. It doesn't need to insert any additional firmwares.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Just forgot to mention , you should insert the kernel module after the installation via " sudo modprobe wl ".

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Now I have two entries in the list but no connection. ```$ sudo rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

Comment: First of all remove `bcmwl-kernel-source`. If it still doesn't work, then post output of `dmesg | grep bcm`

Comment: And hard block means a hardware switch in most cases.

Comment: I don't think it's a hardware switch, I have tried with a different wifi dongle which doesn't have any switch and the wifi is in the same state.

Comment: Interesting thing: now, for ```sudo lshw -C network``` The nework is not DISABLED, it's UNCLAIMED

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/770490/broadcom-wireless-drivers-unclaimed-after-installing-update-16-04 This question solved my problem, thanks a lot!